# if-statement concerning restrictions greater/smaller

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

I want to programm an if-statement which restricts an matrix to the interval (-1) to 1.

input:

```
alpha=matrix(c(-2,0.5,3,0.2,0.8,0.5,0.2,0.8,0.1),3,3)
```

so it results in

```
alpha>1
    [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE

alpha<(-1)
    [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

How can I now programm a restriction which sets the values which are TRUE here to 0.99 and -0.99 like

```
if(alpha<(-1)){alpha[]=-0.99}
if(alpha>1){alpha[]=0.99}
```

so that the output of alpha is

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] -0.99  0.2  0.2
[2,]  0.50  0.8  0.8
[3,]  0.99  0.5  0.1
```

How to programm the (if) condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use logical indexing on the lefthand of an assignment operation:

```
> alpha [ alpha < -1 ] <- -.99
> alpha [ alpha > 1 ] <- .99
> alpha
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] -0.99  0.2  0.2
[2,]  0.50  0.8  0.8
[3,]  0.99  0.5  0.1
```

The R `if` is not a good function for data manipulation. Learn to use `[<-`. Spend a lot of time reading `?"["`. The R `ifelse` is also useful but not necessarily appropriate for matrix operations.